# Can you take back your curse?

Tags: allah

One of my cousins husband left her for another woman. Out of anger I cursed that woman. But when I realized I felt sorry. Will Allah accept my apologies or he will put the curse back on me?

Answer (score 1):

Ask for forgiveness. Allah is most merciful and most forgiving.

You repented your curse. The curse itself is not the main thing, but the language most likely used, and the hate in the curse.